# Missing component of a 4D vector

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

I need to calculate the missing component of a 4D vector, when I know that one of the dimensions is always positive and less than or equal to the magnitude.

In other words, I have four variables x, y, z, t, and a constant magnitude of 1.

The t dimension is always positive between 0 and 1 inclusive. Can I calculate all of the four variables, when I know any three of them?

How? If not possible, why?

Comment: you mean that $||(x,y,z,t)||=1$ and $0\le t\le 1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to your previous question suffices: you compute

$$t = \sqrt{1 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}.$$

for instance. To find $x$ from $y, z, t$, you'd use

$$x = \sqrt{1 - (y^2 + z^2 + t^2)}.$$

Comment: How do I get the sign of x, y, z or t in a consistent way? Given the above constraints.

Comment: You can solve for $t$ consistently because you know it's always positive. But for any of $x, y, z$, you're in trouble. Consider $(3/13, 4/13, 0, 12/13)$. If I give you $(3/13, 4/13, 0, ?)$, you can fill in the missing item with the first formula above. But if I give you $(?, 4/13, 0, 12/13)$, then the missing $x$-value could be $3/13$ or $-3/13$ -- both work, because there's no constraint on $x$ being positive. Sorry to disappoint you...